# What is the Dark Knight tag intended to be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) tag reads as follows:

> The Dark Knight is one the nicknames for the DC Comic superhero Batman and the name of a 2008 live action feature film. Also refered to as the Caped Crusader and the Darknight Detective, Batman is a founding member of the Justice League.

Based on this description I'm not sure what this tag is used for. Is it be supposed to a synonym for the the [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) tag, or about the 2008 movie, *The Dark Knight*?

It's [current usage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) would indicate it's for questions about the *The Dark Knight* film, but my [suggested edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4734) to make the tag better reflect this was rejected because:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost

If it's supposed to be a synonym for the [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) tag then it's currently lacking one. The synonym should be created, and a new tag for *The Dark Knight* needs to be created. Either way the tag should be edited to clearly state what it's intended to be used for. Having the additional information about other uses of the term in the excerpt is just confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synonymizing "Dark Knight" to "Batman" might not make sense (and consequently, the tag wiki needs to be changed), but at the same time, "Dark Knight" does not unambiguously refer to the 2008 movie. It also refers to [a current comic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Dark_Knight) featuring the Caped Crusader, to say nothing of the confusion with the [Frank Miller series from the 80s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns), which was also published under the "Dark Knight" moniker.

In trying to keep with the other tags that have this problem, I tried to find other examples in our tagging, but I only found [stargate-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate-movie) with two questions. Somewhat curiously we don't even have a separate tag for Peter Jackson's adaptation of *The Lord of the Rings*.

So why not just disambiguate the tag and create [dark-knight-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight-movie)? Or perhaps [dark-knight-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight-film), since there's barely a precedent for overlapping tags right now. [dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) should just be kept empty, or if that's really not amenable, synonymized to [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) since you're not going to go wrong tagging a question about a Batman property [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman).

Comment: +1 Making a [tag:dark-knight-film] tag and just removing/synonym [tag:dark-knight] seems like a good solution to avoid all of the problems raised.

Comment: A similar, but not identical issue would be [tag:harry-potter] which refers to the universe and a specific character therein.  AFAIK, Harry Potter doesn't have the nickname issue that Batman/The Dark Knight has.

Comment: @Keen The [tag:harry-potter] tag could be renamed to [tag:harry-potter-series], and the base tag could be used for the character (or [tag:harry-potter-character] could be added).

Comment: Are the various works called *Dark Knight* different adaptations of the same story, or are they unrelated? If they're unrelated we really need to clarify the tags, if it's like e.g. [tag:lord-of-the-rings] we tend to use [tag:novel] or [tag:movie] in the few cases where it's useful to make the distinction (many askers are interested in both).

Comment: @Gilles Christopher Nolan's trilogy draws inspiration from Frank Miller's work, but so does all modern Batman and it's not a direct adaptation (it's about an aging Batman coming back from retirement). One saving grace is that while it was originally published as *Batman: The Dark Knight*, later reprintings called it *Batman: The Dark Knight Returns*. Don't know much about the new series other than it came out after Nolan's Dark Knight. From what I can tell, it's not a direct adaptation, though.

Answer (score 3):

**Whatever its current usage is intended to be I suggest it be made into the tag for the movie *The Dark Knight*.**

[dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) is the most natural name for the tag, and also follows the convention of other tags on the site (including [dark-knight-rises](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight-rises)) where leading the "the" was removed. Naming it to something else would just be confusing for users.

Furthermore, having a shared tag, one intended to be used for both the film *and* as a generic Batman tag is both redundant and bothersome.

The redundancy comes from the fact we already have [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) as an overarching Batman tag. Having a second tag for this which isn't a synonym is just confusing, and makes it harder for users to track down relevant questions (do users really need to perform a separate searches for [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman) *and* [dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight)?). Making it into a synonym wouldn't work, since the tag is *also*  intended to be used for *The Dark Knight.*

The latter problem arises from the fact only way a user can filter questions about the movie with a shared tag is if *all* questions about the film are tagged with [dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie). Although I can see the merit for this in some situations, it's completely unnecessary when we have a perfectly good tag available to use for questions about the film ([dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight)). I don't see any reason why we should require users to bother searching [dark-knight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-knight) [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) for questions about *The Dark Knight* unless we absolutely have to. We should be making things easy for users, not more difficult.

**tl;dr:** There's no reason for this to be a shared tag, so let's just make it a tag solely for *The Dark Knight*.